# How does the merge robot reach out to cookie-only users?

Tags: support, user-accounts, account-recovery

« [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or Google / Facebook / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous) » pretends to deal with account merge for « Anonymous / unregistered / cookie » users.

But it also mentions « After you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can confirm your ownership, we will initiate a merge. »

Having done so, not the Stack Exchange team, but obviously a robot sent a mail to one of the account's email: I had to click a link to confirm my request. But the other account's email has no email when it is a cookie-auth account.

How does the Stack Exchange team reach out to the no-email-account's user?

(It seems the proposed procedure doesn't deal with this part of the question / of the possible situation = *[Regain access to account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356888/regain-access-to-account)* .)

All in one sentence: « When the merge-robot has to reach out both account's contacts to check that "both" agree to merge, how does he manages this for a cookie-only account? »

Comment: well, you did use the contact us form, that either has or asks you for your e-mail. You contact SE, not the other way around.

Comment: @rene you write "you contact SE" . True. But then SE answers : "after you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. " and that is the other way around. Issue is not how they reach me, but how they reach the owner of one account to be merged, when this account is cookie-only-registered and has no mail.

Comment: That is not the other way around. It says *reach out to verify that you own both accounts*. 
You are the single owner of both accounts. If you have access to that account SE can ask you to perform an action you can only do on the other account, for example update the about me of that cookie account. And I assume SE uses additional info to verify that you're not attempting to take over the account that belongs to  someone else. They only need to talk to you, no other person is involved, there is no one else to contact.

Comment: There is only one "me" but there are 2 accounts. One with a mail, one with no mail but cookies, and both have to confirm.
Now I guess that for the cookie-only account to confirm, the robot asks with a dialog displayed on screen once i log into that account ?
It means that requesting a merge will not help me recover access to that account :-(

Comment: I still can't grasp the premise of this question. When I post as an unregistered user (guest) it asks for my name *and email (required but never shown)*. That is the email the recovery instructions are sent to.

Comment: I have updated my OS and lost access to the no-mail cookie-only account. This situation seems a blind point in documentation and in answers... untill now.

Answer (score 1):

The understanding I reach is : When the user has lost access to his cookie-only account, the account's owner cannot be reached by the merge robot and no merge is possible. [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or Google / Facebook / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous) doesn't deal with this situation and could probably be improved.

Answer (score 0):

The [contact form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) asks for your email, as shown below:

[image]

That's how they reach you.

Comment: Thanks @Ollie for caring. It looks like i wasnt understood so i edited the question title and text to be more precise and, i hope, more clear : the reach-out issue matters for the no-email account. When the merge-robot has to reach out both account's contacts to check that "both" agree to merge, how does he manages this for a cookie-only account ?